# I'd like to give my website an onion address and make it Tor-accessible, while using TailsOS. How would I do that?

Tags: configuration

I would like to give my website an onion address and make it Tor accessible, while using TailsOS. Its currently on clearnet. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you run into a problem? https://community.torproject.org/onion-services/setup/

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your web server is listening on localhost port 80.

Add lines like this to your torrc, replacing *hidden_service_name* by a name of your choice:

```
HiddenServiceDir /Library/Tor/var/lib/tor/hidden_service_name
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80
```

Restart Tor.

Source: https://community.torproject.org/onion-services/setup

Answer (score 1):

Tails includes 'Onionshare' - to deliver a static website you can launch onionshare, select 'publish website' point to the root directory that holds your website and that is 'job done'